# How can I perform a search in mongoose where a field (which is an array) contains something?

Tags: mongodb, find, mongoose

Say I have `things` in database with this schema:

```
{
    tags: [String]
}
```

I have `tags` array like this: `["tag1", "tag2"]`
now I need to search in `things` and get only those which contains my tags.

I've searched and found the `$where` operator [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D) but it's not what I need. I was wondering there should be something like
`db.things.find( { $where: "this.tags.contains(<my tags somehow>)" } );`
in mongo or something like this in mongoose. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find document with array that contains a specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `$all`.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all

Here are a couple of examples from mongoose:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/query.test.js#L396

On a side note, `$where` is typically not scalable.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB query syntax allows you to match an element array like that:

```js
.find( { tags: 'tag1' } )
```

And, of course, it's working with Mongoose :)

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element