# Find document with array that contains a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have this schema...

```
person = {
    name : String,
    favoriteFoods : Array
}
```

... where the `favoriteFoods` array is populated with strings. How can I find all persons that have "sushi" as their favorite food using mongoose?

I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
PersonModel.find({ favoriteFoods : { $contains : "sushi" }, function(...) {...});
```

(I know that there is no `$contains` in mongodb, just explaining what I was expecting to find before knowing the solution)

Answer (score 990, accepted):

As `favouriteFoods` is a simple array of strings, you can just query that field directly:

```js
PersonModel.find({ favouriteFoods: "sushi" }, ...); // favouriteFoods contains "sushi"
```

But I'd also recommend making the string array explicit in your schema:

```js
person = {
    name : String,
    favouriteFoods : [String]
}
```

The relevant documentation can be found here:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/

Comment: This works also if `favouriteFoods` is:
`favouriteFoods:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Food'}]`

Comment: As someone new to Mongo coming from an RDBMS like MySQL, to find that such solutions work so simply without needing JOINs and additional tables makes me wonder why I haven't started on Mongo sooner. But that's not to say either DBMS is superior over the other - it depends on your use case.

Comment: Don't mistake it. Even if it's a list of dict, you can still query it this way. Sample:

 `PersonModel.find({ favouriteFoods.text: "sushi" }, ...);
 person = {
    name : String,
    favouriteFoods : [{text:String}]
}`

Comment: What happens when I want to find an Array that contains at least two strings?

Comment: @AeroWang use this 
`db.person.find( { favouriteFoods: { $all: ["sushi", "sashimi"] } } )`
 will return all person loving both "sushi" and "sashimi" someone pointed it a few answers below

Comment: @yaya your answer is the best and easiest way to handle this query.  Perhaps also worth mentioning, if you want to exclude results that have a scalar value for the specified field instead of an array, you can specify:  `PersonModel.find({favouriteFoods: {$elemMatch: {$eq: "sushi"}}})`

Comment: Confirmed that this works with Long data type, too.

Answer (score 235):

There is no `$contains` operator in mongodb.

You can use the answer from JohnnyHK as that works. The closest analogy to contains that mongo has is `$in`, using this your query would look like:

```
PersonModel.find({ favouriteFoods: { "$in" : ["sushi"]} }, ...);
```

Comment: Is this correct? Isn't mongodb expecting an array of values when using $in? like { name : { $in : [ "Paul", "Dave", "Larry" , "Adam"] }}?

Comment: Huh? This is unnecessary. `$in` is used when you have multiple query values and the document needs to match one of them. For the reverse (which is what this question is about), JohnnyHK's answer is correct. I was going to downvote but I guess this answer may be helpful to other people who end up on this page.

Comment: But this helped me to actually query with several values :D 
Many thanks !

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was actually looking for, the way to search for multiple values: `PersonModel.find({favouriteFoods: {"$in": ["sushi", "hotdog"]}})`

Comment: @MalcolmOcean is correct, in that the $in operator is for the reverse, having an array as the *value*. The *field* being an array is what the question is asking about. However, if *both* the field and the value are arrays, then both this answer and JohnnyHK's are relevant, meaning you do need $in.

Comment: Any way to use `$in` property inside `$or` like `$or: [ { _id }, { domains: { $in: [ domains ] } } ]`?

Comment: @MalcolmOcean thanks for not unvoting - this answer was what i was looking for :)

Comment: What does this do exactly? Does this work like this: "Query all people whose favorite foods contain e.g. sushi *and* hotdog"? Or is it "... sushi *or* hotdog"? Nvm, the next answer says $in is like *or* and $all is like *and*

Answer (score 154):

I feel like `$all` would be more appropriate in this situation. If you are looking for person that is into sushi you do :

```
PersonModel.find({ favoriteFood : { $all : ["sushi"] }, ...})
```

As you might want to filter more your search, like so :

```
PersonModel.find({ favoriteFood : { $all : ["sushi", "bananas"] }, ...})
```

`$in` is like OR and `$all` like AND. Check this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Comment: Sorry, this is an incorrect answer to my question. I am not looking for an exact match but just for arrays that contains at least the value specified.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer to your question! For one value there is no difference in using $all or $in. If you have several values like "sushi", "bananas", $all is looking for persons that have "sushi" AND "bananas" in their favoriteFood array, if using $in you are getting persons that have "sushi" OR "bananas" in their favorite food array.

Comment: yeah, there is no $contains but $all is sort of it

Answer (score 123):

In case that the array contains objects for example if `favouriteFoods` is an array of objects of the following:

```
{
  name: 'Sushi',
  type: 'Japanese'
}
```

you can use the following query:

```
PersonModel.find({"favouriteFoods.name": "Sushi"});
```

Comment: This is easily the best answer. Much easier to use when you're in a hurry.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. If you are dealing with querying an array of nested documents in MongoDB, this is how you do it. Not sure if it is the most efficient but if that's all you're trying to do, this is all you need.

Answer (score 35):

In case you need to find documents which contain NULL elements inside an array of sub-documents, I've found this query which works pretty well:

```
db.collection.find({"keyWithArray":{$elemMatch:{"$in":[null], "$exists":true}}})
```

This query is taken from this post: [MongoDb query array with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335197/mongodb-query-array-with-null-values)

It was a great find and it works much better than my own initial *and wrong* version (which turned out to work fine only for arrays with one element):

```
.find({
    'MyArrayOfSubDocuments': { $not: { $size: 0 } },
    'MyArrayOfSubDocuments._id': { $exists: false }
})
```

Answer (score 10):

Incase of lookup_food_array is array.

```
match_stage["favoriteFoods"] = {'$elemMatch': {'$in': lookup_food_array}}
```

Incase of lookup_food_array is string.

```
match_stage["favoriteFoods"] = {'$elemMatch': lookup_food_string}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are some ways to achieve this. First one is by `$elemMatch` operator:

```
const docs = await Documents.find({category: { $elemMatch: {$eq: 'yourCategory'} }});
// you may need to convert 'yourCategory' to ObjectId
```

Second one is by `$in` or `$all` operators:

```
const docs = await Documents.find({category: { $in: [yourCategory] }});
```

or

```
const docs = await Documents.find({category: { $all: [yourCategory] }});
// you can give more categories with these two approaches 
//and again you may need to convert yourCategory to ObjectId
```

`$in` is like OR and `$all` like AND. For further details check this link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Third one is by `aggregate()` function:

```
const docs = await Documents.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$category' },
    { $match: { 'category': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(yourCategory) } }
]};
```

with aggregate() you get only one category id in your category array.

I get this code snippets from my projects where I had to find docs with specific category/categories, so you can easily customize it according to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Though agree with find() is most effective in your usecase. Still there is $match of aggregation framework, to ease the query of a big number of entries and generate a low number of results that hold value to you especially for grouping and creating new files.

> ```
>   PersonModel.aggregate([
>             { 
>                  "$match": { 
>                      $and : [{ 'favouriteFoods' : { $exists: true, $in: [ 'sushi']}}, ........ ]  }
>              },
>              { $project : {"_id": 0, "name" : 1} }
>             ]);
> ```

Comment: What error are you getting, please provide in detail?

Answer (score 2):

For Loopback3 all the examples given did not work for me, or as fast as using REST API anyway. But it helped me to figure out the exact answer I needed.

`{"where":{"arrayAttribute":{ "all" :[String]}}}`

Comment: You are a life saver, thanks!
Where is that documented and I missed it? Can you post the link please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case You are searching in an Array of objects, you can use `$elemMatch`. For example:

```
PersonModel.find({ favoriteFoods : { $elemMatch: { name: "sushiOrAnytthing" }}});
```

Answer (score 1):

With **populate** & **$in** this code will be useful.

```
ServiceCategory.find().populate({
    path: "services",
    match: { zipCodes: {$in: "10400"}},
    populate: [
        {
            path: "offers",
        },
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone new to MongoDB and isn't familiar with constructing MongoDB JSON query objects inside the `find*` methods, you can leverage the mongoose [Query Builders](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html). These are great for newcomers or to encourage consistent querying within your team.

Given the following documents:

```js
{
   "_id": "65440e1e5d9811753b6be8e1",
   "favoriteFoods": [ "corn", "sushi", "pasta" ],
},
{
   "_id": "6545612721b99c8cff188a0a",
   "favoriteFoods": [ "eggs", "pizza", "rice" ],
}
```

You can chain the `where()` and `in()` methods to match the specified documents:

```js
const person = await PersonModel.find().where('favoriteFoods').in(['sushi']);
// Returns
[
   {
      "_id": "65440e1e5d9811753b6be8e1",
      "favoriteFoods": [ "corn", "sushi", "pasta" ],
   }
]

const person = await PersonModel.find().where('favoriteFoods').in(['sushi', 'pizza']);
// Returns
[
   {
      "_id": "65440e1e5d9811753b6be8e1",
      "favoriteFoods": [ "corn", "sushi", "pasta" ],
   },
   {
      "_id": "6545612721b99c8cff188a0a",
      "favoriteFoods": [ "eggs", "pizza", "rice" ],
   }
]
```

A full list of Query Builder methods can be [found here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html).

Answer (score -8):

If you'd want to use something like a "contains" operator through javascript, you can always use a Regular expression for that...

eg.
Say you want to retrieve a customer having "Bartolomew" as name

```
async function getBartolomew() {
    const custStartWith_Bart = await Customers.find({name: /^Bart/ }); // Starts with Bart
    const custEndWith_lomew = await Customers.find({name: /lomew$/ }); // Ends with lomew
    const custContains_rtol = await Customers.find({name: /.*rtol.*/ }); // Contains rtol

    console.log(custStartWith_Bart);
    console.log(custEndWith_lomew);
    console.log(custContains_rtol);
}
```

Answer (score -26):

I know this topic is old, but for future people who could wonder the same question, another incredibly inefficient solution could be to do:

```
PersonModel.find({$where : 'this.favouriteFoods.indexOf("sushi") != -1'});
```

This avoids all optimisations by MongoDB so do not use in production code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: This is incredibly inefficient compared to the accepted answer; it circumvents all of the optimisation Mongo puts in behind the scenes for a straight find as in the accepted.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed in my case though! Thank you "user" :)