# How do I find documents that match a list of tags?

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a list of blog posts similar to the below

```
[
    {
        title: "Post #1",
        tags: ["foo", "bar"]
    },
    {
        title: "Post #2",
        tags: ["bar", "baz"]
    },
    {
        title: "Post #3",
        tags: []
    },
    {
        title: "Post #4"
    },
    {
        title: "Post #5",
        tags: ["qux"]
    },
    ...
]
```

How can I use the standard `/posts` GET method to find:

- all the posts that match the `foo` tag?
- all the posts that match the tags `foo` AND `bar`?
- all the posts that do not have tags?

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-relations-basic has various examples that might be related to your question.

Comment: First two matches are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515167/how-to-query-models-by-a-property-that-is-an-array/27050795#27050795 In short, to my understanding support of such kind of queries is very limited. But should work for mongo datasource. As for existence I would try either `inq` where operator http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Where+filter#Wherefilter-Operators with empty array (never tried myself though), or do a custom implementation on server side using datasource specific code. E.g. using $size or $exists operators for mongodb...

Comment: In the end I just ditched Loopback and wrote a RESTful API with Express. IMHO its DB query capabilities are too limited for most real-life cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard /posts GET method to find:

- all the posts that match the foo tag?

  /posts?filter={"where": {"tags": {"inq": ["foo"]}}}
- all the posts that match the tags foo AND bar?

  /posts?filter={"where": {"and": [{"tags": {"inq": ["foo"]}},{"tags": {"inq": ["bar"]}}]}}
- all the posts that do not have tags?

  /posts?filter={"where": {"tags": []}}

Comparing to db queries, Loopback is built on top of Express and supports most of the queries as it uses native database drivers internally to build queries.