# How to make a Mongo Find Query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I come from MySQL world so mongo queries are a bit difficult to make considering I can't really make sense of mongo style queries. I am trying to make a query for finding a string. The problem is from my very primitive knowledge about mongodb queries, the query I made isn't working. I tried it in mongoose as well in mongo shell.

**Schema:**

```
mongoose.Schema({
        doctorID : String,
        patientIDList : Array // array of strings
    });
```

**Query Objective:**

I want to find a doctor with `doctorID` and then look inside the `patientIDList` for an ID `xxx`. If the `patientIDList` doesn't contains `xxx` then add `xxx` in the list otherwise just add nothing.

**Query:**

The 2 queries I tried

```
MyModel.findOne({'doctorID':newAppointment.doctorID}, {'patientIDList' : newAppointment.patientID}, function(err){...});

MyModel.findOne({'doctorID': newAppointment.doctorID, 'patientIDList': newAppointment.patientID}, function(err){...});
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make a query?

Comment: somebody please help

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bit of challenge to switch from a SQL to NoSQL DB and other way around. What you are trying to do is check if a value exists in an array. If the array is a string array you can simply query for the value in array.

```
MyModel.findOne({doctorID : newAppointment.doctorID}, {patientIDList :newAppointment.doctorID}, function(err, res){
    console.log(err, res);
})
```

Further read: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element

Relevant Question: [Find document with array that contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value)

Comment: Gives this error: e2 [Error: Can't use $eleMatch with Array.]