# retrieve items from a mongodb collection in meteor

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have a collection "vegetables" who has many vegetables inside like this one :

```
vegetables = [{
            nom: "zuchini",
            recolte: [{
                month: ["august", "november", "december"],
                desc: ""
            }]
```

I want to find all vegetables who have for example "august" in the array "month, if i do for example :

```
Vegetables.find({ recolte[0].mois : "august});
```

i have an error when i do this...do u know how  i can access to this element ?

thanks by advance

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value).  In your case, I think the problem is the `[0]`.  I don't think this is needed.

Comment: it's not a duplicate because here it' different problem,  it's an object inside an array and without the [0] i also have an error...

Comment: So, is `Vegitables` a collection or an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Vegetables` is a collection:

```
Vegetables.find({"recolte.month": "august"});
```

If `Vegetables` is a collection and it also has a `vegetables` field:

```
Vegetables.find({"vegetables.recolte.month": "august"});
```