# How to get all docs which contain another doc in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## Objective

I have a recipe document that contains an array of ingredients (also documents). I wish to obtain all recipes which contain a certain ingredient.

## Background

Lets say I have a recipe document that looks like the following:

```
{
        name: "Red Velvet Cake",
        ingredients: [{
            name: "roasted beet",
            amount: {
                quantity: 0.5,
                metric: metrics[0]
            }
        }, {
            name: "orange",
            amount: {
                quantity: 0.25,
                metric: metrics[0]
            }
        }],
        preparation: "Mix everything and have fun!",
        Source: "Super Smoothies, p. 142"
    }
```

Now, lets say I have a collection with many recipes, and I want all recipes that have "oranges" as an ingredient.

## What I tried

To achieve this i am trying the following using mongodb's console:

```
db.smoothies.find( { ingredients: {name: "orange"}} )
```

However, it doesn't work.

I read in other questions like  [Find document with array that contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value) that some people use keywords like `$all`, `$in` and `$exists` but I am unsure how these can help me.

## Question

How do I make my query work?

Comment: Use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to query the elements of an array `db.smoothies.find({ "ingredients.name": "orange" })` or [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents) as `db.smoothies.find({ "ingredients": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "orange" } } })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your query like this:

```
db.smoothies.find( { "ingredients.name": "orange"} )
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about MongoDB, but this is how i would do it with vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var recipes = [{
  name: "Red Velvet Cake - No Orange",
  ingredients: [{
    name: "roasted beet"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Red Velvet Cake",
  ingredients: [{
    name: "roasted beet"
  }, {
    name: "orange"
  }]
}]

console.log(recipes
  .find(function(a) {
    return a.ingredients.some(function(b) {
      return b.name == "orange"
    });
  }))
```

Polyfills if needed:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill

Comment: When half the code in your answer is polyfills, and 80% of the remaining code is the OP's data, you may want to reconsider how you're structuring your answer. In other words, don't include the polyfills (___Especially___ not in a `<script>` tag in the snippet's HTML field). Just link to them if you think it's really necessary.