# search in array filed of mongodb by mongoos in query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection `Events` in my Mongodb and it has an array filed called `for_who`.

This field is for checking if a user id is in this array, so this user can see this `Event`. I want to get the `Events` that `for_who` field contains `user_id`.

This is my current query:

```
Events.find(
    { for_who: { "$in" : [user_id]} } 
).lean().exec(function(err , obj) { ... });
```

my schema:

```
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
  id                : { type: Number , required: true , unique: true } ,
  title             : { type: String , required: true } ,
  created_at        : { type: String , required: true } ,
  for_who           : { type: Array } 
});

var Events = mongoose.model('Events', eventSchema);
```

Comment: This looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value, but what you're trying should also work, even though `$in` isn't required. What's not working about it?

Comment: No I`ve seen that but doesn`t work!!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the schema definition for `Events`, the value of `user_id`, and the document you're expecting the query to return?

Comment: I edited my question and included event schema

Comment: Because `for_who` is typed as a simple `Array`, you have to do the casting to ensure `user_id` is the same type as the elements of `for_who`. That's why I was asking for you to also provide the value of `user_id` and the document your expecting to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
Events.find().then((events) => {
  var userData = events.find((v) => {
    return v.for_who === user_id
  })
  if(userData){
    //user was found
  }
})
```

i think this cloud work

Comment: I think you didn`t understand my question. I want to get events by user_id. The users have access to see the event, defined in "for_who" array in database

Comment: it does what you wanted. gets all the records and then filters them based on the given user. its working but not the way you wanted