# Node js, Mongoose query to match id with values stored as comma separated string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, find, match

I am new to the Mongoose and NodeJS world.

I have product document where I am storing category ids as shown below.

```
"reviewscount" : "2",
"overallrating" : "4.5",
"urlkey" : "strive-shoulder-pack",
"productid" : "2",
"categoryid" : "3,7,4",
```

Now wanted to fetch all the products belongs to one category based on category Id.

I tried below code, but getting empty result

```
Product.find({ "categoryid" : { "$in" : [ categoryId ] } }, function (err, products) {
console.log(products);
}
```

Am I doing it wrong way?

Comment: Why are you using a string? use an array instead of string.

Comment: @Exos, If I change it to array, my above query work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would check whether the whole `categoryid` is equal to something in the in-array.

You basically got two options, the first (preferred) is to store your `categoryid(s)` as an array instead of csv and use a simple query as seens in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18148872/4299313).

The second option is to manually ([mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js)) parse the `categoryid` against your Id, but that wont scale very well ([besides other problems](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)).

`Product.find({$where : 'this.categoryid.indexOf("' + categoryId + '") != -1'});`

Answer (score 1):

```
Product.find({ "categoryid" : { "$in" : [ categoryId ] } }, function (err, products) {
console.log(products);
}
```

for this type query you need to **convert** in your schema.

```
"reviewscount" : "2",
"overallrating" : "4.5",
"urlkey" : "strive-shoulder-pack",
"productid" : "2",
"categoryid" : [3,7,4] // convert in your schema make categoryid:[Number]
```

to insert in `categoryid` use `$addToSet` with `$each` if you want unique value in array.