# Search the id's of an array in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this HomeSchema

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema;


homeSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    administrator: {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},


users: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Home', homeSchema);
```

I want to query whether a specific user in that users array based on user._id? I know this is rather simple, but how do I do this? Do I have to use $elematch?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value

Comment: I would argue against that @JohnnyHK. I have this users: array of ObjectId's and hence I believe it is not like searching for strings?

Comment: The approach is the same whether it's an array of strings or ObjectIds. In this case it would be `{users: user._id}` to find Home docs where `users` contains `user._id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$in** for this. This query will search for all the **userId** (this should be an array) that are present in your users array in your collection. if you want some details of the users you can use populate for that.

```
var query = {users : {$in:userId} }
```