# Find documents with array that contains a specific value in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

According to the answer provided in this link:  [Find document with array that contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value), i have tried getting the items in java using this statement

```
searchQuery.put("arrayMine", new BasicDBObject("$in","[xxx]"));
OR
searchQuery.put("arrayMine", new BasicDBObject("$in","xxx"));
```

But it keeps saying the $in value must be an array while my arrayMine is an array. What should be the correct syntax in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variants you have are treating the value of `BasicDBObject` as `String`.

Use

```
searchQuery.put("arrayMine", new BasicDBObject("$in", Arrays.asList("xxx"))
```