# How to query arrays in mongo or mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following models:

```
User:
  id: ObjectID

Group:
  id: ObjectID
  users: []
```

If I had a group collection like:

```
Group = [{
    id: 1,
    users: [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    users: [1,6,7]
  }
]
```

How could I get all the `Groups` that container the User ID `1` in the `groups.users` array?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stackoverflow+mongodb+query+array+contains&t=ffab&ia=qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find document with array that contains a specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value)