# MongoDb: Find documents which contain tags/keywords matching given string

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

i have a collection (Foo), which has "keywords" field. I want to find documents, which match given string (have at least one matching keyword), and sort them by number of matches.

```
Foo:
{name: 'Foo1', keywords: ['example', 'sample', 'keywords']},
{name: 'Foo2', keywords: ['keywords example', 'find']},
{name: 'Foo3', keywords: ['search']},
{name: 'Foo4', keywords: ['example keywords', 'find', 'example', 'search']}
```

So for string `"This is example keywords search"` should return documents in this order:

1. Foo4 (3 matches - 'example keywords', 'example', 'search')
2. Foo1 (2 matches - 'example', 'keywords')
3. Foo3 (1 match - 'search')

I'm using Symfony3 and DoctrineODM if it makes a difference. Thank you all for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find document with array that contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value)

Comment: @Severin i don't see how your link is similar to my question, as i have string as an input, which cannot be simply exploded into single words

Comment: Have you tried anything or just throwing a task on SO hoping somebody will solve it?

Comment: @malarzm i have tried something like **{$where: "\"This is example keywords search\".match(this.keywords)"}** , but it's not working at all - it returns documents which have empty keywords array, no matter what string i use. I have no more ideas how it could be solved, that's why im asking here

Comment: You can try splitting the keyword string into array of keywords and compare this array against keywords in document to count the no of matches  and sort the documents by matching count inside an aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB supports the counting of matches per document, and you can even [create a text index which observes multiple fields with custom weights](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/). (It is even useful to discard any automatic keyword-detection you would build for other DBs.)