# Update documents in a collection if one of the document field value exists in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `collection1` with `collection1Column` and another column `presentInArray1`,

```
--------------------------------------------
| collection1Column | presentInArray1      |
--------------------------------------------
| A                 | null                 |
| B                 | null                 |
| C                 | null                 |
| D                 | null                 |
| E                 | null                 |
--------------------------------------------
```

I have an `array1` like this:

```
let array1 = ['A', 'C', 'D'];
```

Now I need to update `collection1`'s column `presentInArray1` only if an exact match of `collection1Column` is found in `array1`. In the example given - the matches are **A**, **C** & **D**.

One possible javascript solution I have thought is the following:

- Get all the values from both the collection & array.
- Once the values are available, take up one by one values from `collection1`'s `collection1Column`  and iterate on `array1` to find a match.
- Once the match is found, will update the `presentInArray1` with `true`

In this scenario - How do I update documents in the collection `collection1` if one of the document field `collection1Column` value exists in `array1`?

Also, here is the code I have tried so far:

```
collection1.update({
    'collection1Column': {
      $in: array1
    }
  }, {
    $set: {
      'presentInArray1': true
    }
  }, {
    multi: true
  },
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

This also seems to be not working. I'm not sure why:

```
{"result":{"n":217,"nModified":0,"opTime":{"ts":"6833283007906840577","t":13},"electionId":"7fffffff000000000000000d","ok":1,"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":"6833283007906840577","signature":{"hash":"W1KNoy0a9d2iTU3OiIa2jlc4y00=","keyId":"6803936209337843714"}},"operationTime":"6833283007906840577"},"connection":{"id":5,"host":"cluster0-shard-00-01-foobar.mongodb.net","port":27017},"modifiedCount":0,"upsertedId":null,"upsertedCount":0,"matchedCount":217,"n":217,"nModified":0,"opTime":{"ts":"6833283007906840577","t":13},"electionId":"7fffffff000000000000000d","ok":1,"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":"6833283007906840577","signature":{"hash":"W1KNoy0a9d2iTU3OiIa2jlc4y00=","keyId":"6803936209337843714"}},"operationTime":"6833283007906840577"}
```

This looks very expensive in terms of memory and performance to me.

Please suggest!

> In simple words, how to perform [V Lookup](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/vlookup/how-to-pull-values-from-another-worksheet-in-excel) in `MongoDB`?

MongoDB server version: 4.2.6

Comment: **1)** Did you try `$in` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value ? **2)** What is the value that you wanted to update in `presentInArray1` for docs which match with `A`,`C`,`D`? **3)** what is your DB version ?

Answer (score 1):

```
collection1.update({
    'array1': $collection1Column
  }, {
    $set: {
      'presentInArray1': true
    }
  }, {
    multi: true
  },
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Assuming `collection1Column` is not array type

If the field holds an array, then the $in operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array (e.g. , , etc.)

For more Details: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 0):

I used `updateMany` instead of `update` and it works.