# Express mongoose filter array of ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user schema were it has a role ref which is an array of ids and i want to filter user with role id.

```
const users = await User.find(
  { roles: { $in: [params.role] } },
  "-password"
)
  .populate({
    path: "roles",
  });
```

This is my user schema.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    contact: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Contact" },
    roles: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Role" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Here params.role is single role id and i getting empty user result here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find document with array that contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value)

Comment: no $in works for array of strings but not for array of ids i guess and User.find({ roles: params.role }); also not working.

Comment: You can use it for ObjectIds as well. For this, convert strings to ObjectId and then filter like this; ```await User.find({ roles: { $in: params.role.map(role => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(role) } }```. You can test it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mEMj9j07bma . The found data returns when filtering by ObjectId. If you remove ObjectId from the param role and filter it as a string, then the data doesn't return

Comment: params.role is single id and await User.find({
      roles: { $in: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(params.role) },
    }); this doesnt worked.

Comment: The parameter must be an array to filter with `$in`. If it's a single id, then, can you try it like ```{ $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(params.role)] }```

Comment: ok i tried this, await User.find({
        roles:{ $in: [new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(params.role)] }
    }); but empty user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `params.role` is a single value then you don't need `$in`. Since `User.roles` is an array of type `ObjectId` mongoose should cast the search string to an `ObjectId` for you so you can just search in the normal way but make sure there is a value in `params.role` and it's not actually `req.params.role` that you mean:

```js
console.log('params.role=', params.role);
const users = await User.find({ roles: params.role}, "-password").populate({
    path: "roles",
});
```

Comment: Thanks the issue is solved. The main issue was that i stored the roles array ids as string not as objectId.